# Is that expression right?

Tags: expressions

If we want to explain how important a topic is, can we say:

> No doubt that this topic is important.

Comment: Without any further context, *no doubt this topic is important* sounds to me like it is going to be followed by *but...*. Try *this is undeniably an important topic*.

Comment: @Minty But if I say "No doubt this topic is important", is it grammatically correct? Or should I say "There is no doubt that this topic is important"?

Comment: The sentence "There is no doubt that this topic is important" is perfectly good English. The expression in the Q. is missing a verb.

Comment: @MathewHany on it's own, I would say it's not grammatically correct. If there is no verb, *no doubt* would usually function as an adverb in a concessive construction like *no doubt he meant well, but he hurt her very badly* - but a concessive construction needs two parts, and *no doubt this topic is important* has only one, as does *no doubt he meant well*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's common to use 'no doubt' alone as it's a phrase:

***no doubt***

: DOUBTLESS 
(https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/no%20doubt)

Look at some examples from Reverso.context.net:

"Godfrey's doing cartwheels, **no doubt."**

"Somebody this socially isolated **no** **doubt** has mental issues."

"Lessons can **no doubt** be learned from compliance procedures applied by other conventions."